# How can I combine two plots?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot `x` from 0 to 1, and `x^2`, from 1 to 2?

```
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Thus, in a way, I want to combine the two functions into one plot.

Comment: `Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}], Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html?q=Piecewise) or similar functions.

Comment: @Karsten7. Indeed, it's a bit hard to say if this question is about piecewise plotting, or multiple plots.

Answer (score 11):

Combine `Plot`s with `Show`, and remember to use `PlotRange -> All`:

```
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Another option, as Karsten7. stated, is to use piecewise functions with non-numeric default value outside their domain:

```
Plot[
 {Piecewise[{{x, x < 1}}, Null], 
  Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 1}}, Null]},
 {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Then again, if you are really interested of not having separate plots, you probably want a direct `Piecewise` expression like:

```
Plot[
 Piecewise[
  {{x, x < 1},
   {x^2, x >= 1}}],
 {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]